# c# DataGrid bound to List

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a dataGrid bound to a List object and this works fine by calling...

```
dgList.DataSource = carList;
```

However I have code that updates the carList on background threads by polling servers and also deletes based on age.  The datagrid does not seem to update at all, I tried calling `.Update()` and that has no effect.

Is this possible?

The list is defined as

```
List<Car> = carList = new List<Car>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) won't work because it only redraws the control:

> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.

The simplest solution is likely to rebind using `DataSource` again:

```
dgList.DataSource = carList;
carList.Add(car);
dgList.DataSource = null;
dgList.DataSource = carList;
```

Comment: Ah yes, that worked.  However I had to 

`dgList.DataSource = null` first

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebind the data with [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kf1c24y6.aspx) again

as for WinForms: have you tried to reset the source again?
If not use a BindingSource instead of the raw list.

Comment: `dgList.DatBind()` does not work.  I believe that is only available for ASP.net?  This is a windows form.